# How to pass more than one value to a serializer for a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

I've got a model with a ManyToManyField (field name : postSpot).

To create a new object in the database using the Django API, I send a FormData in the body of a POST request (then parsed by the ViewSet).

The issue is that :

- when the postSpot field of the data sent to the serializer only contains a single value, the deserialization works perfectly, the new object is created in the database ;
- BUT when I try to pass more than 1 value in the postSpot Field (let's say : 49 and 63), it never works : I always get a 400 error "Bad request".

I've tried to send the set of values using all kinds of formats :

- an array of values [49,63] (which is the usual format to send a set of values to a serializer)
- an array of objects [{pk:49};{pk:63}]
  and many other things…
  I've even tried to send a single value, but inside an array : [63] and it does not work. I always get the 400 Bad Request error.
  The only way I have it work is by sending in the request a single value, in a simple numeric format, in this field.

But I have created a ManyToManyField because I need to store a set of values in the postSpot field !

How can I pass to my serializer a data that will be validated and will contain the set of values I want to store in my postSpot field ?

The model :

```
class Post(models.Model) :
    postSpot = models.ManyToManyField(Spot,related_name='posts')
    postAuthor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postText = models.TextField(blank=True)
    postPicurl = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_pic_path, blank=True, null=True)
    postTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-postTimestamp']
```

The serializer (as you may know, you can't directly write the values of a ManyToManyField : you must use .set() on the instance)

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self,validated_data):
        authorProfile =  UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        post = Post(
            postAuthor = authorProfile,
            postText = validated_data['postText'],
            postPicurl = validated_data['postPicurl'],
            postTimestamp = timezone.now()
        )
        post.save(post)
        post.postSpot.set(validated_data['postSpot'])

        return post

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**EDIT**
For those interested in the solution, I've found a way to pass data to the serializer and store them in the Many-To-Many field :

- you can NOT send the values of the MTM field in the corresponding field of the POST request, otherwise the data is rejected by a 400 Bad Request error.
- send the data in an additional field of the request, and whatever (valid) single data in the target field.
- in the serializer, override the create method to do the following actions: create the new object without data in the MTM field (and return the new instance to reference it later) ; then, manually process the additional data, stored in the Context data of the request, to add the values to the MTM field. To achieve this, use the .add() method to add each value individually, one by one.
  Please note that, even if you send an array, the context will contain a string that you need to parse manually. It was more convenient in my case to add as many different variables to the request, and parse each corresponding property of the context.

My new serializer :

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self,validated_data):       
        authorProfile =  UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        post = Post(
            postAuthor = authorProfile,
            postText = validated_data['postText'],
            postPicurl = validated_data['postPicurl'],
            postTimestamp = timezone.now()
        )
        post.save(post)
        for key, value in self.context['request'].POST.items():
            if key[:9] == 'postSpots':
                post.postSpot.add(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add logic to save `many-to-many` field in Serializer

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    def create(self,validated_data):
        authorProfile =  UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        post = Post.objects.create(
            postAuthor = authorProfile,
            postText = validated_data['postText'],
            postPicurl = validated_data['postPicurl'],
            postTimestamp = timezone.now()
        )
        post.save(post)

        for i in validated_data['postSpot']:
            postspot_obj = Spot.objects.get(id=i['id'])
            post.postSpot.add(postspot_obj)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. I've tried, but the 400 error "Bad request" did not disappear, it seems to be related to the incoming data. I've found a solution : send data in the serializer's context, then I could deserialize them.